# Database schema issue - dev studio 2.0 Marshmallow

Tags: java, android, database, android-studio, refactoring

I have an application designed and running on Android nexus 5 running marshmallow.  The application was developed using android studio 2.0.  Recently refactored one of the database tables to use Integers instead of Reals.  As part of the refactoring, I changed the database version number in my db helper class.

Querying the data stored in the refactored table shows the refactored data values to still be stored as Reals.  I have tried the following:

1. ran the same code base on a simulator phone and querying shows the table changes were correctly picked up.  That is Real values have been replaced by Integer values.
2. Uninstalled the application from the nexus 5 and reloaded the code with the database version incremented again.  Data is still stored in the refactored table as Real values not integers.
3. Tried step 2 with powering on and off the phone after removing the application and before installing the modified code.  Refactored values still storing data as reals.

Any ideas or pointers?  Can't believe that the android environment is such a POS

Comment: My database helper class does override onUpgrade which does drop the database tables if they exist.

Comment: Have found the following in working with android studio 2.0 and 2.1. I: 1. Data affinity differs for Integer fields when comparing the data on a 6.1 phone versus the simulator.  2. Data inserted with a unique constraint causes data values making up the constraint to be changed on insert on a 6.1 phone.

Comment: As an example:  UNIQUE (" + DistanceEntry.COLUMN_DATE + ", " +
                RunnerContract.DistanceEntry.COLUMN_LOC_KEY + ") ON CONFLICT REPLACE).  Stepping through the insert I see that android supplied java module change the date value from the value passed in the values parameter.